# Ag-Grid is not loading in Internet Explorer version 10

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am facing an issue with the ag-grid library which is not loading in IE 10 but working fine in IE 11.
I also attached a screenshot of the console error for more information about the error
[image]

Comment: IE 10 isn't supported in any supported OS. It hasn't been supported or updated for a *long* time. It doesn't support the features needed by current libraries. Why are you asking about *IE 10*?

Comment: In any case, the [supported browsers page](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-supported-browsers/#desktop-browsers) shows that only IE 11 is officially supported.

Comment: You could probably try using an older version of ag-grid, from a time they did support IE10. Or simiply tell your customers to use the current browser versions on their machines. IE11 is available on all currently supported OS versions and the oldest one, Windows 7, is reaching end-of-life on January 14 2020.